# Why this small chunk of code is consuming 97,868 k memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, sharepoint

I have this small chunk of code and I can't understand why it's taking soo memory.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://consotvo.internal.com/upi"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = mySite.OpenWeb())
            {
                //foreach (SPFile file in web.Files[0])
                //    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);

                SPFile file = web.Files[0];

                using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                {
                    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wb in manager.WebParts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(wb.Title);


                        //wb.Dispose();
                        //manager.Web.Dispose();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is consuming **97,868 k** even after code has been executed even thought i didn't closed console window yet. my problem is that i want to open 3000 webs (different url) and make changes to a webpart ***but too much memory is being consumed***.

**Update**

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
```

***Alone this line is adding 40,000 k***

Comment: How do you measure this amount?

Comment: At the moment, it's impossible to assess the overheads of loading and JITting all of the assemblies/code you use, and the actual memory impact of your single request. At the very least, you should measure, say, doing a single request vs doing 10 or 20, to establish what the actual memory usage for each request is likely to be. Also, how are you measuring the memory consumed?

Comment: What makes you think that too much memory is consumed? Just because 1 web consumes x, that doesn't imply that 2 webs would consume 2x. Also, keep in mind that `using` statements (or the `Dispose` method they call) have nothing to do with memory consumption.

Comment: Do not forget that SharePoint's core is a nuclear reactor that generates a **lot** of objects.

Comment: Use a memory profiler.

Comment: Also - Debug or Release build? I'd guess at Debug since there's nothing to stop it exiting otherwise. On my machine (Win 7, x64, VS 2013), a simple console app that just runs `Console.ReadLine()` consumes ~20MB as a Debug build (drops to ~6MB for Release)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened when i run code in "release" build

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are opening the connection the to the site and which would then pull down the source of the page and all of that source needs to be stored somewhere so unless you chunked it into a text file or a database it is going to need to consume as much memory as the server is sending back.

Comment: What makes you think that pulls down the source of the page?